# Best WPF alternatives for .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, graphics, .net-2.0

i have to write a WinForm C# desktop application in .NET 2.0 to make it compatible with the majority of computers out there.
This application will ( or at least should ) have a pretty nice interface, with a lot of graphics and custom skinned controls ... since i can't use WPF ( available only starting from framework 3.5 ), what alternatives do i have if i don't want to make every control to be handled by my paint routines ( overriding OnPain ) ?
I was thinking about using some HTML rendering framework such as this one http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32376/A-Professional-HTML-Renderer-You-Will-Use but even the best one would require modifications.

Any free alternatives/hints/whatever to make a pretty interface without WPF ?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify, the 2.0 framework is a project requirement, i can't change this thing even if i'd like to, so this is **not** the point of this discussion.

Comment: who told you that .net 3.5 is not compatible with the most of windows PC's? From what i know you can use .net 3.5 from win XP to win 8. Or are you under the impression that most pc's run windows 98? cause thats the only os that supports .NET 2.0 as a final version.

Comment: i never wrote that 3.5 is not compatible with the most of windows pc :)  but that a lot of computers don't still have > 2.0 installed ... anyway this is a project requirement i can't change, i have to write it in 2.0 and there's nothing i can do about it even if i'd like to.

Comment: that is not necessarily true, as most people are picking up on windows 7 wich has it preinstalled.

Comment: maybe you are right, maybe not ( i honestly don't know :) ) but this is not the point of my question ^_^

Comment: i see that after your edit but your reasoning of using 2.0 is still written, thats why i commented.

Comment: if i hadn't written anything, someone would ask "why you have to use 2.0 ?" ... so, whatever i wrote, that's not the point.

Comment: I think your best choice is to use a set of skinnable controls (DevExpress, or other). But you'll need a license for that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you're not going to like any answer which you might get. Your basically have two options: waste your employer's time and money by looking for an alternative to WPF, which is a Microsoft-supported industry standard for Desktop applications*, or changing the requirement of using .NET framework v2.0.

Version 3.0 of .NET was shipped together with Windows Vista, so any computer out there running Vista and above will have the .NET framework capable of running WPF. If some of your client run Windows XP, it might be possible they don't have .NET framework 3.0, it would be much easier for you to just take that chance (and supply a .NET Framework redistributable installer with your application).

Again, in both cases, I believe, you will have to explain the pros and cons to your employer (or whoever set the requirements), and let them decide.

Comment: * for all intents and purposes, for building LOB desktop applications

Answer (score 0):

There are some tools that will compile/link your .net application binaries so that you do not need the .net framework on client pcs.

http://spoon.net/studio

http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/

Seriously though, I would not work for an employer who does not want to upgrade their machines to .NET 4 or above.